# Prevent url's from appearing as links in mail clients

Tags: html, email

I'm sending an HTML mail from my app, this mail contains URLs, is there a way to prevents from mail clients to show these URLs as links?

for example:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>http://www.google.com</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

will generate" http://www.google.com

instead I want it to generate a static text.

any thoughts?

Comment: No, this is a UI feature of the receiving mail client, designed to make their users' lives easier (and reduce the amount of selecting-text, copying-text and pasting-text into an address bar). Nothing you can do about it so far as I know. And I second @Kimvais' comment regarding *why* you would want to make your email recipients' lives more troublesome...

Comment: There are decent reasons to want to prevent the email client from auto-generating links.  The UX of mail clients is not infallible.  Sometimes it doesn't make sense to have more than a couple links in an email, and if the client is automatically converting every URL-looking string into a link, you can have an email that is LESS optimized for the end user (i.e., it's too busy and loud) rather than more.

Comment: Phooey. Sending a special promotional link to users of my website, link is unique to each user, I mention the name of the site (mysite.com) in the email, and then later in the email is their special link. later I recieved several help requests that their promo didn't work because they mistakenly clicked the homepage link instead. Totally legit use case.

Comment: In our case, we have a database instance name in the email that looks like "asdf:sqlserver:dbtier.machine.client.com" where the "dbtier.machine.client.com" isn't really a URL, but on the phone email it appears a clickable link which goes to silverjewelry(dot)com because apparently that's where client(dot)com goes to. We just want the text to show without the link.

Comment: Phishing and client colour choices are my two main reasons to want to unlink : )

Comment: We have a good many military customers whose email servers strip out hyerlinks. So, there's at least one good reason.

Comment: The use case I have is for magic links. They work great until you are using a mobile email client, Gmail on iOS for example, that will open the link in a special instance of the browser. That then invalidates the magic link and leaves the user only logged into the isolated browser instance. I want to add the link so it can be easily copiable without having to try to fight the auto open feature.

Comment: **Related:** [How to disable an email link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013625/how-to-disable-an-email-link/12740620#12740620)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is a feature of some mail clients and there's no foolproof way to stop them from doing whatever they want with the message contents.

You could try to trick the mail clients by wrapping the addresses in empty tags and hope that they aren't smart enough to see through it:

```
<td><span>http</span><span>://</span>www.<span>google.</span>com</td>
```

Comment: i was also thinking about doing something like: `<td><a href='#' style="text_tecoration:none; color:#000; cursor:defualt">http://www.google.com</a></td>` what do you think?

Comment: I'm sure there are legitimate reasons for wanting to do this, and I think at this point it's been made clear that in the general case this is not a smart thing to do.

Comment: if you wanted to email a user with the location of a file that is not on their machine like //blah/blah/blah/blah.doc you wouldn't want this as a link, simply as a representation of a directory.

Comment: @Kimvais Our company has a dot in its name and clever e-mail clients need to change it to link every single time it is mentioned in e-mail. I call this incredibly stupid.

Comment: Fortunately we also own the domain so that the autogenerated links are valid. I also saw some products where the name of product is a bit different (e.g. Zboží.cz as name of product vs zbozi.cz as URL)

Comment: Right now, I need to send URL to my colleague and mark different parts of that URL with different colours to explain them. Yet Gmail insists that it knows better, it removes colour a creates a LINK! How cool is that?

Comment: Also you can add this code `&zwnj;` example `<span>www</span>.&zwnj;google&zwnj;.<span>com</span>` this way i skip the ios smart

Answer (score 20):

Use a "zero width space" character: `&#8203;`

It does as the name implies. It adds a space in your string but the space takes up zero width so instead of looking like two strings, it looks like one.

Comment: Works in iOS, thanx! Remember to wrap the URL in a <nobr> tag to prevent it from breaking to the next line on the end of a line.

Comment: Huh? Why would you want to do that!! If you copy an email address you get with your selection garbage characters...

Comment: Nice idea, but doesn't work with Outlook 365 desktop client : (

Answer (score 3):

I have found the accepted answer doesn't work for Outlook 2013. I have had success with the following:

```
http<a href='#' style='text-decoration:none; color:#000;'>://www.google.</a>com
```

Setting the style `cursor:default` is not honored by Outlook 2013, but if you only make the middle of the url a hyperlink then a user can still select the link text without the cursor pointer appearing.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that largely depends on the mail client and thus is beyond your control. The only option would be to not make it a URL. E.g. write www.google.com (which the user can copy/paste just like the URL.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have any luck in preventing MacMail and Yahoo Mail from creating links out of any text string ending in .com (or other domain extension). After hours of testing (even 'href=""' and 'href="#"' did not work), I finally inserted my own URL and then manipulated the CSS and inline styles to remove the mail clients' link styling.

Answer (score 0):

Adding in hidden line break elements in the right places seems to have fixed this for me (for now) in almost all clients, including desktop Outlook, according to [Litmus's](https://www.litmus.com/) tests (Apple Mail desktop looks like the main exception).

```
https:<br style="display: none;"/>//www.w3<br style="display: none;"/>.org/TR/2020/WD-WCAG22-20200227/
```