# Remove the automatic link in HTML Emails

Tags: html, css, email, html-email

I'm currently making an HTML email for a company, but whenever I try and type their address it automatically turns into a link with underlining and everything. Is there a way to make it so that it just reads as text?

```
 <span class="text-center site">COMPANYSITE.COM/SWITCH</span>
```

edit: to clarify, I'm trying to make it show up as COMPANYSITE.COM/SWITCH rather than [COMPANYSITE.COM/SWITCH](http://COMPANYSITE.COM/SWITCH)

Comment: I would try to add the style: `text-decoration:none; color:black` to the span to solve the styles, however I'm unsure if it will still be clickable.

Comment: I would think it's the email client you're using, that turns a normal string into a link. You can add in html comments to prevent that: `COMPANYSITE<!-- -->.COM<!-- -->/SWITCH`.

Comment: To be honest clickable is fine, client just has a very specific way they want the text to appear. I added text-decoration:none !important; to the css (i'm using an inliner application) and it doesn't seem to be working. I'll try adding it directly in though.

Comment: ^Agree, email clients all do entirely different things to HTML/CSS

Comment: Neat resource - https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: this is all that's there .site{
 text-decoration:none !important;
 color:white;
}

Comment: It has nothing to be with styles as @KIKOSoftware comments must be the way it reads the HTML, maybe when detects any text with **.com**  translate it to a link ....

Comment: oy, does that mean I'm gonna have to put like, a space between the . and com? ugh.

Comment: Possibly :( - I know this is a bit crazy but attempt a double declaration, `style="text-decoration:none !important; text-decoration:none;"`

Comment: sigh. nope that didn't work. I think I'm just gonna have to keep the spaces there while testing and then in the final thing just tell them to manually remove the hyperlink when they're sending it out.

Comment: you can try pointer events : `.site{pointer-events:none}`

Comment: @DaniP nah the pointer events didn't work. I think it really is just the email client.

Comment: XD yeah check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625880/prevent-urls-from-appearing-as-links-in-mail-clients ... the multiple span solution seems nice or add the blankUTF space too

Comment: oh hell yeah the blankUTF space worked great thanks! Apparently there are issues with outlook but it seems like everything has issues with outlook.

Comment: you can use a global class to target client that read css in the head of the document or you can use an anchor tag without the href and give the anchor tag styles (color and text-decoration), it should work.